# Evaluation of $\int \frac{1-\sin x}{(1+\sin x)\cos x}dx$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $$I=\int \frac{(1-\sin x) dx}{(1+\sin x)\cos x}$$

I tried in the following way:

$$1-\sin x=1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=2 \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Similarly $$1+\sin x=2 \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

So

$$I=\int \tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right) \sec x \: dx=\int \sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right) \sec x \: dx-\int \sec x \:dx$$

If $$J=\int \sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right) \sec x \: dx$$ Applying parts for $J$ we get

$$J=-2\sec x \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)+2\int \sec x \tan x \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)dx  $$

But i am clueless from here

Comment: Hint: multiply the numberator and denominator by $1+\sin(x)$

Answer (score 9):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
I&=\int \frac{(1-\sin x) dx}{(1+\sin x)\cos x}
\\\\&=\int \frac{(1-\sin x)\cos x dx}{(1+\sin x)\cos^2 x}
\\\\&=\int \frac{(1-\sin x)\cos x dx}{(1+\sin x)(1-\sin^2 x)}
\\\\&=\int \frac{(1-u)du}{(1+u)(1-u^2)}\quad (u=\sin x)
\\\\&=\int \frac{du}{(1+u)^2}
\\\\&=-\frac{1}{1+\sin x}+C.
\end{align}
$$

**Edit**. (from @[Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/202857/bernard)) The Bioche rules  are rules that give hints on the useful substitutions for the integration of rational functions in $\sin$ and $\cos$. Namely you consider the differential form $f(\sin x,\cos x)dx$, and substitute successively $−x$ to $x$, then $π−x$, and finally $π+x$. If the differential form is invariant by one of these substitutions, set $u$ equal to the function which is invariant by the same substitution – which is $u=\cos x$, $u=\sin x$ or $u=\tan x$, respectively.

If it happens the differential form is invariant by two of these substitutions, one may set $u$ equal to a trigonometric function of $2x$.

The worst case is when none of these substitutions work. As a last resort, one sets $u=\tan \frac x2$, since there are standard formulae which express $\sin x,\cos x$ and $\tan x$ as functions of $u$.

Comment: You may mention *Bioche's rules*  to justify the method.

Comment: What's that "Bioche's rules"? Any link, please?\

Comment: @Joanpemo I found [a paper on it](https://www.deepdyve.com/lp/wiley/the-rule-of-bioche-and-its-application-to-the-solution-of-o01oOOBv56) after Googling the term. Basically, it's a way to convert a trig expression with multiple trig functions into terms of one trig function, which is, in this case, $\sin x$.

Comment: They're rules that give hints on the useful substitutions for the integration of rational functions in sin and cos. Namely you consider the differential for $f(\sin x, \cos x)\mathrm d\mkern 1mu x$, and substitute successively $-x$ to $x$, then $\pi -x$, and finally $\pi+x$. If the differential form is invariant by one of these substitutions,  set $u={}$ the function which is invariant by the same substitution – respectively $u=\cos x$, $u=\sin x$ or $u=\tan x$.

Comment: @Bernard See my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, @NobleMushtak and Bernard and Olivier

Comment: @Olivier Oloa: Fine. I'll delete my comment. Just an add-on: if the differential form is invariant by two of the substitutions, one may  set $u ={}$  a trigonometric function of `2x`. B.t.w., there's a small typo at the end of your edit (`differential for` instead of `form`).

Comment: @Bernard Please, feel free to edit my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\;1+\sin x\;$ , so you get ( observe that $\;\cos x=(1+\sin x)'\;$):

$$\int\frac{\cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2}dx=-\frac1{1+\sin x}+K$$

Comment: I would proceed in the same way +1

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1-\sin x}{(1+\sin x) \cos x} d x 
= & \int \frac{1-\sin x}{(1+\sin x) \cos x} \cdot \frac{1+\sin x}{1+\sin x} d x \\
= & \int \frac{\cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2} d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{1+\sin x}+C .
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the integrand by $(1+\sin x)$< then the integral becomes $$I=\int \frac{\cos x dx}{(1+\sin x)^2}=\frac{-1}{1+\sin x}+C$$